# Custom HTML in Sharepoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage, html, content, richhtmlfield

I have been trying to get HTML inserted into my webpage via sharepoint, as opposed to hard coding it in the layout page (for obvious reasons..).

I have tried using the Content Editor and entering the HTML, but it continuously displays the raw code as opposed to rending the HTML as I thought it would have.

Attached is a screenshot of the outcome. Is it that I'm missing a step or am I using the wrong approach to get this done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `content editor webpart` and select "`Edit Source`" option from the `ribbon`.

Put your HTML there and save the page.

if  you are using `SharePoint 2013` you can use a `Script Editor` web part instead and put your HTML in that webpart

Comment: This it, please mark the question as answered

Comment: Only the person asking the question can mark the question as answered

Comment: That is it indeed. The Script Editor works perfectly. Much respect!